# MongoDB find value match for a property in array within array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a document structure as follows:

```
{
    "field1": "value",
    "field2": "value",
    "items": [
        {
            "inField1": "value1",
            "inField2": "value2",
            "votes": {
                "count": 2,
                "people": [
                    {
                        "username": "user1",
                        "image": "http://image/to/user1/profile.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "user2",
                        "image": "http://image/to/user2/profile.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "inField1": "value3",
            "inField2": "value4",
            "votes": {
                "count": 1,
                "people": [
                    {
                        "username": "user1",
                        "image": "http://image/to/user1/profile.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need all **item**(single Object of items field) where in any **people** property of **votes** property has a username as ***user1***?

In above mentioned example it should return both the **items**, as both of them contain ***user1*** in username property, but if I search for ***user2*** then onl the first item should be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question was found in another SO link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155210/2641194

First, we have to **$unwind** both the arrays and then data for each *people* is a separate document, and then our **$match** comes into picture to pick out only those who satisfy the query:

```
db.collection('topic').aggregate(
    [{
        "$unwind": "$items"
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$items.votes.people"
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "items.votes.people.username": "user2"
        }
    }], function(err, docs) {
        if(!err) {
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                // code
            });

        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
        db.close();
    });
```

If you need to further understand **$unwind**, and how does it work then please refer to this mongodb documentation link: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregation framework, First unwind items array and match them.

Try this:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
    [{
        "$unwind": "$items"
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "items.votes.people.username": "user2"
        }
    }]
)
```

Comment: Nope! Not working... Any other suggestions?