# Retrieve only the queried object from nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregates

Having the following document in my Mongo I'm trying to get the object with specified id. Here is my Mongo document.
Mongo version: 2.6

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c1ae9ac1bd31d4eb4d546d"),
    "footers" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "web",
            "rows" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "abc",
                    "elements" : [ 
                        {
                            "id" : "def",
                            "type" : "image",
                            "url" : "http://example.com"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "id" : "ghi",
                            "type" : "image",
                            "url" : "http://example.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm looking for an object with id "def", and I want to obtain this result:

```
{
    "id" : "def",
    "type" : "image",
    "url" : "http://example.com"
}
```

Below I cite the example of code that I tried to make search of this object.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "footers.rows.elements.id": "def"
    }},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$footers.rows.elements"
    }}
])
```

And the result is:

```
{
    "_id" : [ 
        [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "id" : "def",
                    "type" : "image",
                    "url" : "http://example.com"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "ghi",
                    "type" : "image",
                    "url" : "http://example.com"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)".

This answer will help you with more details [Mongodb unwind nested documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154184/mongodb-unwind-nested-documents) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241733/224743 specifies this should work in MongoDB 2.2+)

For your specific example, you could do something like:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {"$match"  : { "footers.rows.elements.id": "def" }}, 
    {"$unwind" : "$footers"}, 
    {"$unwind" : "$footers.rows"}, 
    {"$unwind" : "$footers.rows.elements"}, 
    {"$group"  : { "_id": "$footers.rows.elements" }}, 
    {"$match"  : { "_id.id": "def" }}
]);
```

Notice the multiple "$unwind" chainings and also the final "$match" which is needed to reapply the conditions for the $unwind-ed documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful.