# MongoDB - unpack rows from a embedded document into their own column

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

### The Problem

So I have a MongoDB document that looks like so:

`Awards`:

```
    [
      {
        "year": "2017",
        "winners": [
          {
            "name": "james",
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "adam",
            "id": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "year": "2018",
        "winners": [
          {
            "name": "mary",
            "id": 3
          },
          {
            "name": "jane",
            "id": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And I'm basically trying to expand out the winners from each year so that the schema is roughly `(year, winner_id)` i can later use that for a join I plan on doing. Something like this:

```
[
   {
     "year":"2017",
     "winner_id":1
   },   
   {
     "year":"2017",
     "winner_id":2
   }, 
   {
     "year":"2018",
     "winner_id":3
   },
   {
     "year":"2018",
     "winner_id":4
   }
]
```

#### What I've Tried

so intuitively, I'm looking for something like `$unwind`, but the problem is that `winners` is not an array.

- I tried `db.awards.aggregate({'$unwind':'$winners.id'})` but that didn't work. (gave an empty result)
- So afterwards I thought `db.awards.aggregate({'$unwind': {'$objectToArray':'$winners.id'}})` but that didn't work either. (gave an error)
- According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154184/mongodb-unwind-nested-documents) I should do this:

```
db.awards.aggregate(
 { '$project': {
    _id: 1,
    'winners': 1
  } },
{'$unwind': '$winners'},
{'$unwind': '$winners.id'}
)
```

but even that didn't work, I still get the embedded document for each `winner`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your posted documents are not valid json. Please repost them correctly

Comment: fixed them. apologies, long day

Comment: the `winners` attribute is still an object and not an array. Therefore it is still invalid JSON. Are you really sure that `winners` is not an array?

Comment: yes. it's an array of embedded objects. That's kinda my problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is invalid JSON. In assume that `winners` attribute is very likely an array.

I can see three additional issues in your aggregation commands:

1. You should pass the aggregation pipeline as an array as well to the `aggregate` function.
2. the syntax for `$project` is different in aggregation pipelines. You do not define which fields should be included. You do define the actual mapping
3. I do not understand why you wnat to unwind the winners id. The attribute to unwind should be an array and in your example there is only the `winners` array.

I think it is easier to do the `$unwind` before projection

```
db.awards.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: { path: '$winners' }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        year: '$year',
        winner_id: '$winners.id'
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ebiZh6erZYD)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `winners` and use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to get it at ROOT position

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$winners" },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$winners",
          { "year": "$year" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yjqt5JWma56)

Comment: I like this one, replaceRoot is very powerful and this finally explained to me what it does!